# Avoid unselecting region when copying text in Emacs using cua-mode

Tags: emacs

Is there a way of *not* deactivating the mark of a region after copying it to the clipboard? (I'm using `Emacs`  24.2.90 and `Cua-mode`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following in your initialization:

```
(setq cua-keep-region-after-copy t)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get it back using `C-x C-x`

C-x C-x is bound to `cua-exchange-point-and-mark`. It will work only if the variable `cua-enable-cua-keys` is set to `nil`.

Comment: You should provide the additional config which makes that work for you, because it's certainly not default cua-mode behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to keep `cua-mode`.